# Resolve "please first complete your account by adding a payment method" in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My phone (Galaxy s3, OS v4.1) is having two Google accounts. One is added when I purchased my phone, and other I have added now.

Now I have installed my application for testing and it's having in-app purchase. When I tried to purchase, every time I get message like `please first complete your account by adding a payment method`.

1. I have installed signed app which is drafted on Play.
2. I have configured test account on Google developer console.

The Google account, configured in my phone, is having admin access to Google developer console. That is why I want to test in app product with my other Google account but when I am redirected to Google play market, It shows my first account every time. How can I test with my other account configured in my phone?

Is there any system like, this is primary account or this is secondary account?

Comment: I think in app purchase works with primary account only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the google account from your phone with which you don't want to test.

This is the bug filed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37758).

Comment: There is no option right now to test with my other Google account. Because Google does not allow. I should accept Google policy and your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but I had a different experience with the same message.
(please first complete your account by adding a payment method)

My eclipse adt and sdk were out of date. Updating those also updated the Trivial drive project which then had more detailed information in the readme file about how to properly setup and run the app.